# Stream StringBuilder to file

Tags: c#, string, file, streaming, stringbuilder

I need to create a large text document.  I currently use `StringBuilder` to make the document and then call `File.WriteallText(filename,sb.ToString)`.  Unfortunately, this is now starting to throw out of memory exceptions.

Is there a better way to stream a `StringBuilder` to file or is there some other technique I should be using?

Comment: Could you not just do File.WriteAllText with the text you are adding rather than putting into a stringbuilder and doing it all at once?

Comment: @Bali to call `WriteAllText` you need to have all the text, so that won't help with memory issues

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Instead of using `StringBuilder`, try using `TextWriter` (which has a broadly similar API, but which can write to a number of underlying destinations, including files) - i.e.

```
using(TextWriter writer = File.CreateText(path))
{
    // loop etc
    writer.Write(...);
}
```

More generally, it is worth separating the code that knows about files from the code that knows about how to write the data, i.e.

```
using(var writer = File.CreateText(path))
{
    Serialize(writer);
}
...
void Serialize(TextWriter writer)
{
    ...
}
```

this makes it easier to write to different targets. For example, you can now do in-memory too:

```
var sw = new StringWriter();
Serialize(sw);
string text = sw.ToString();
```

The point being: your `Serialize` code didn't need to change to accomodate a different target. This could also be writing directly to a network, or writing through a compression/encryption stream. Very versatile.

Answer (score 5):

Just use a `StreamWriter` that writes to a `FileStream`:

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("filename.txt")) {
  ...
}
```

This will of course mean that you can't change the text that is already written, like you can do in a `StringBuilder`, but I assume that you are not using that anyway.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why not streaming directly into the stream?
You could use the [TextWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can use StreamWriter and write to the file directly.